# WordPress load right image size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website where HQ images will be uploaded.
To have better UX and not load big images or unnecessary images i need to load smaller sizes of images on phones and original size on tablets & desktop.

Have been searching on Google, Stack-overflow and some other websites for answer but could not find any good.
The only and best answers so far have been to use css or javascript and do display:none .
The problem with that is that all those things will anyways load but not be visible.
I am looking for a solution to load only images with mobile size on mobiles and desktop size on desktops or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible with ajax, javascript to detect browser width and load content from there

for example inside loop you can get post thumbnail

```
<?php while(have_post()) ?>
    <div postid="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="thumbnail-1"> 
        <!--load form ajax--> 
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

in script

```
<script>
    var id = $('thumbnail-1').getAttr('postid');
    $.ajax(get_thumbnail.php, { id: postid, width: screen.width, height:screen.height }, function($data){
        $('thumbnail-1').Html($data)
    }
    );
</script>
```

inside get_thumbnail.php

```
function($id, $width, $height){
    if(width > 650){
        return get_post_thumbnail($id, 'medium');
    }
    else{
        return get_post_thumbnail($id);
    }
}
```

you have to find some way to loop through each class in javascript ex thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 and get data from ajax.

and that is one scenario, different image loads may needs to be implemented differently

**I'm not test this code there should be typos ALOT**. I write just to get an idea

PS. there is no other way coming to my mind. I'm not gonna do this. we live in 2015 and we got 4G :) I'm just optimize my images.